# Which data model to use for nominal independent variables and continuous dependent variable?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, random-forest

I have a data set with two nominal features (which are my independent variables) and a continuous numeric output variable (i.e. dependent variable) between range of -10 to 10. What kind of predictive modelling algorithm should I use in this case?

**user_id** 31030
16144
23098
14273
18419
5782
34059

**joke_id** 110
109
6
86
134
14
62

**Rating** 2.75
5.094
-6.438
4.406
9.375
-1.781
6.25

I have almost 1 million records in train data set. Test data set has around 200k records.

Comment: How many levels do each of your nominal features (user_id, joke_id) have? What types of predictions are you interested in making?

Comment: @EdM user_id has 41,000 levels and joke_id has 139 levels. These 41000 users have rated these 139 jokes on a scale of -10 to +10 in training data set containing 1million records and i need to predict ratings of test dataset containing 200k records.

Comment: I'm assuming that the same 139 jokes are in both the training and test sets; correct me if I'm wrong. Is that also true of the users, or are those in the test set a completely different group of users? Do you just care about overall ratings of each joke, or do you want to make detailed predictions about how individual users will rate each joke?

Comment: @EdM yes, you are absolutely right, its the same 139 jokes being used in the test set rated by the same set of users.And the prediction is regarding how each user will rate each joke (the way they have rated in the train set).

Comment: In that case you are looking for a [recommender system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system) as @AndreaLanci suggested. Even though you're not going to make recommendations to these (or other) users, the goal is the same: in the test set, estimate how the users will rate the jokes, given how the same users rated other jokes in the training set. What you seem to need is what's called a collaborative filter (see the Wikipedia page linked above in this comment), and Andrea Lanci's answer is just what you need to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are after a recommendation system.
There is a lot of literature about this problem. I would start looking into matrix factorisation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_factorization_(recommender_systems)

I would also recommend to google "factorisation machines".

Comment: Hi Andrea, no i am not making a recommendation system or something related to it. Actually, feature user_id has 41,000 levels and joke_id has 139 levels. These 41000 users have rated these 139 jokes on a scale of -10 to +10 in training data set containing 1million records and i need to predict ratings of test dataset containing 200k records.

Answer (score 0):

The usual starting place would be linear regression, but the possibilities are vast. You might need some alternate method of regression if the assumptions are violated (e.g. robust regression, quantile regression). In fact, quantile regression might be good even if the assumptions of linear regression are met - depending on what you  are most interested in predicting.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but linear regression gave me a very poor R^2 value of 0.0268. Should I use One Hot encoding (dummy variables) for the independent variables?

Comment: If you got an R^2 of 0.03 from linear regression then it is very likely that nothing will work well. (Unless you did the regression wrong). If your IVs were continuous, they might need some transformation or there might be a nonlinear relationship, but with nominal IVs, that's not possible.  You could look at some graphs (like a parallel box plot) but I think you probably just have variables that don't relate to each other.